# V = I x R -- Voltage (V) as a function of Resistance (R) is Linear; however, Current (I) as a function of Resistance is not Linear -- why?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics

I am totally blanking on the following simple equation (Ohm's law):

V = I x R -- Voltage is Current x the Resistance.

Clearly, One can prove f(R) = I x R is linear:
f(aR) = af(R)
f(R1 + R1) = f(R1) + f(R2)
holds.

However,

g(R) = V / R -- Current as a function of Resistance is not linear -- its an inverse function, as so f(x) = 1/x.

But, how is an algebraic equation that describes the relationship between variables in one form linear, whilst in another form not linear.

Comment: no paradox here

Comment: The relation between the voltage drop and the resistance at fixed current is linear. The relationship between the current and the resistance at fixed voltage drop is not linear. No paradox, the variables in question are different.

Answer (score 2):

The relationship between Voltage and Resistance is linear (if you consider current to be constant), whether you are expressing V in terms of R, or R in terms of V.

The relationship between Current and Resistance in inverse (if you consider voltage to be constant), whether you are expressing I in term of R, or R in terms of I.

You got confused because you changed which pair of variables you were considering the relationship between: from V and R to I and R.

Comment: It is interesting to note that the inverse relationship I = V/R is "inverse" linear in the following sense:

g-inv(R) = R/V -- now the relationship is linear again 

So, a non-linear relation can "hide" an inverse linear relation ...

Comment: What i find interesting here is that a circuit engineer has both readings in mind:

a. multiplying resistance, divides current linear-proportionally
b. adding more resistance reduces the current even faster (due to the inverse non-linear character of the phenomena captured in the inverse equation.

Answer (score 0):

Just as [JonathanZ supports MonicaC](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/275313/jonathanz-supports-monicac) said,

$$V \propto R \therefore R \propto V$$
however, suppose $V$ is equal to a constant $k$

$ I\cdot R = k$, which implies that the function of either $I(R)$ or $R(I)$ are hyperbolic, and therefore non-linear.

A method of proof would be taking the derivative of either function because the derivative of linear functions is always a constant.

We can show $\frac{\partial V}{\partial R} =\frac{\partial}{\partial R}  [IR]$

Assuming I is a constant $\epsilon$ yields $\frac{\partial V}{\partial R} =\frac{\partial}{\partial R}  [\epsilon R]=\epsilon$

And for Current, $\frac{\partial V}{\partial R} =\frac{\partial}{\partial R}  [IR]$

Assuming R is a constant $\epsilon$ yields $\frac{\partial V}{\partial I} =\frac{\partial}{\partial I}  [\epsilon I]=\epsilon$

Since the result is a constant, one can infer $V$ is a linear function of $I$ and $R$
on the other hand,
$$I \propto {1\over R} \ and \ R \propto {1\over I}$$
Differentiating using the same idea that a linear function's first derivative will be constant proves $I$ and $R$ do not have a linear relationship.

$$\frac{\partial I}{\partial R} = \frac{\partial}{\partial R}R^{-1}$$
$$ = -R^{-2}$$

A non-constant result proves $I(R)$ is non-linear, and for $R(I)$,
$$\frac{\partial R}{\partial I} = \frac{\partial}{\partial I}I^{-1}$$
$$ = -I^{-2}$$

Also non-linear; therefore, current and resistance have a non-linear relationship.

Comment: OP is confused about how a pair of linear relationships turns into an inverse linear relationship and you're bringing derivatives into this? I don't see who this answer is for.

Comment: Its nice to see the idea of derivative a constant to prove linear or non-linear -- i.e. via one equation. 

However, I think, it simpler to prove the two equations: f(ax) = af(x) and f(x1 + x2) = f(x1) + f(x2)  -- you can then better see that the inverse (V/R) as a function of R, doesn't fit with neither of the equations above.

But, i am still wondering about the fact that something that exhibits a linear relationship when unversed loses that property -- and in a way, its not lost -- its there but hidden - the inverse gets smaller proportionally to R.